# How to set up a DrawerLayout toggle button in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a DrawerLayout used as a navigation tab. I have everything set up, but now I need a small button that would open it and close it (ActionBarToggle, or something like that). How can I set it up as simply as possible? (Im a relative beginner, so I'm not handling this very well)

it just needs to be a button in the top left corner (like the one the youtube app has) that toggles the drawer open and closed.

Edit: I'm adding my code for the drawer:

```
     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    /***/
    public NavDrawerListAdapter navDrawerListAdapter;
   Fragment fragment;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            categoryItems = new ArrayList<CategoryItem>();
            categoryItems.populate();
           navDrawerListAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this, categoryItems);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(listheader, null, false);
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

   }
}
```

Among other things, there is a simple Adapter (NavDrawerListAdapter), and a simple JavaBean CategoryItem. There is also a small function populate() which simply adds a few elements to the list. All of those function perfectly. All I need now is a toggle button in the top left corner to open and close the navigation drawer.

Comment: can you show some code, are you using default navigation drawer

Comment: check this link hope its helps - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Look at [Android Navigaion Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon) & Download sample from there.

Comment: you should post some code so that we know how much you have tried it

Comment: I added code to explain what I have (I have other elements but not concerning this problem)

Comment: Use Android Studio. It comes with this already setup for you. File -> New Project -> Select the Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_widget);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          return toggle != null && toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
          if (toggle != null)
              toggle.syncState();
     }

     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
          if (toggle != null)
              toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     }
}
```

**Edited:**
Don't forget to add references to support library in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

And import all of:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
```

And check your **styles.xml**, parent theme should be:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: what is wrong? R.string.drawer_open is a string resource it stands for "Open" same thing with close.

Comment: on the ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor I get an error, the constructor is not valid and can't be recognized. I've tried modifying it, fiddling with it, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: Sorry for the weird half-comments and no edits, my Internet is shaky, so I didn't edit it on time.

Comment: when I try to add the "compile... " lines to build.gradle, in the dependencies part, I get an error, 

"Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app_debugCompile'.
Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0

Searched in the following locations:
and then a list of files and locations

Where should I place this?

Comment: I fiddled around a bit, now I get an error when I try to inflate the toolbar
 LayoutInflater inflater1 = getLayoutInflater();
            View toolbartest = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.actionbarhome, null);

     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Toolbar

However, when I don't inflate, I get a NullPonterException on trying to use the toolbar.

Comment: I was missing the "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'' part. Thanks!